# Visual Studio clean/build/rebuild solution not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010

This seems to affect only when I'm trying to perform this action on either the root solution that contains all the others, or a subfolder with multiple solutions in it. I right click on the node I want to clean/rebuild in Solution Explorer and click on the action I want, but nothing happens. Any ideas why? I even reinstalled Visual Studio, but the result is the same.

Comment: Sounds like a corrupt project file.

Comment: @surfasb Could expand on this? I'm no VS whiz. Corrupt how? On a different machine, the same solution opens up just fine. What might be different?

Answer (score 1):

Can you go into the Bin folder and manually delete the files found?  If so, then try the rebuild.  If it fails, then check to see where the Bin folder is actually storing its output.  Also check to see if there are any actions that move files after the build process is complete.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a corrupt project file.

It is an XMl file, but I don't recommend that novices try to fix it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dy88c2e(v=vs.80).aspx

I would do the following:

1. Make a backup copy of **solution** folder
2. Delete everything in the original **project** folder
3. Create a new Project
    a. Make sure you  **add to solution**
    b. For the Location, choose the original project folder
4. Move everything back.
5. Relink References, Namespace, blah blah.

Hope that helps.